# Generating a proxy client for a WCF web service in Java

Tags: java, wcf, wsdl, client

When you are in the .NET world, the task is rather simple: you add a service reference to your project, and svcutil creates a proxy class for you along with the custom data types that the service exposes, if any; all that based solely on the service's WSDL.

What are the ways to do the same in Java? I have a client who is struggling to consume our web service and attempting to assemble and parse SOAP messages manually.

Comment: Have you done _any_ research? You couldn't even present a few options that you found and ask us which is best (still off-topic)?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find any straight answer about this. Sorry, I am not a Java guy, really.

Answer (score 0):

Use the wsimport import tool.

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://example.com/service?wsdl
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/wsimport.html